# user name and password login through ajax.. unable to login

Tags: php, ajax

Controller code below as show unable to login.
 none of the error getting what is the problem i cannot understand how to call through ajax

```
        public function loginn()
            {
                $email=$this->input->post('email');
                $password=$this->input->post('password');

                //$this->load->library('form_validation');

                $this->form_validation->set_rules('email', 'Email or number', 'required|min_length[10]|max_length[30]');
                $this->form_validation->set_rules('password', 'password', 'trim|required|min_length[4]|max_length[40]');

                if ($this->form_validation->run() && $this->Login_model->login($email, $password)) { 
                    $this->welcome();
                } 
                else {
                    $this->form_validation->set_message('check_database', 'Invalid username or password');

                    $this->index(); 

                       }
            }
```

Below code as shown View page send the post values through ajax.script as below.how to pass the post values to controller using ajax.

```
  <script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#fpassf").click(function(){
        //e.preventDefault();
        var email = $("#email").val();
        var password= $("#password").val();


        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "<?php echo base_url() ?>"+"Index.php/Login_cntrl/loginn",
            data: {email:email,password:password},
            success:function(data)
            {
                alert('Successfully login');
            },
            error:function()
            {
                alert('fail');
            }
        });
    });
});
```

the image shown in below
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xd5RL.png)

on click on signin image shown in below
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/s1IXX.png)

Comment: Put your jquery codes

Comment: What is the problem? Errors? Issues? Expected vs actual behavior? Voting to close for lack of details.

Comment: Check your AJAX response & PHP error if you've any. Maybe that'll help you to fig out what's the issue.

Comment: do you really have this url?? ` url: "<?php echo base_url() ?>"+"Index.php/Login_cntrl/loginn",` check it , with you browser

Comment: yes i have that url

Comment: @siddalingappaM can you please open your firefox inspectElement, on tab "Network" and capture an image?? there are some information on request infos

Comment: @siddalingappaM Thanks for image, but i need image of request call, for this: click on sign and then click on you request info on network tab. thanks

Answer (score 0):

It seems that you are using Codeigniter Framework. And Hence I have a doubt with your Ajax URL Path.

You have given

```
 url: "<?php echo base_url() ?>"+"Index.php/Login_cntrl/loginn",
```

But In codeigniter it should be like

```
 url: "<?php echo base_url() ?>"+"/Login_cntrl/loginn",
```

OR

```
 url: "<?php echo base_url('Login_cntrl/loginn') ?>",
```

It can also possible that you are calling this ajax from a script file. Which is not a php file. so the base_url() function will not work there. In that case you have to save base_url into a input variable in a hidden format. and then should be fetch in your ajax code.

```
<input type="hidden" name="myurl" value="<?php echo base_url();">
```

and then ajax one

```
var myurl = $("#myurl").val();
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to separate your basic login action and ajax login action, because both send different response.

PHP Controller:

```
public function ajax_login()
{
    $email = $this->input->post('email');
    $password = $this->input->post('password');

    $this->form_validation->set_rules('email', 'Email or number', 'required|min_length[10]|max_length[30]');
    $this->form_validation->set_rules('password', 'password', 'trim|required|min_length[4]|max_length[40]');

    if ($this->form_validation->run() && $this->Login_model->login($email, $password)) { 
        return $this
            ->output
            ->set_status_header(200)
            // here you tell to the ajax that the login is successful
            ->set_output(json_decode(array('status' => 'success', 'message' => 'PUT_YOUR_SUCCESS_MESSAGE_HERE')))
        ;
    } else {
        return $this
            ->output
            ->set_status_header(200)
            // here you tell to the ajax that the login is failed
            ->set_output(json_decode(array('status' => 'error', 'message' => 'PUT_YOUR_ERROR_MESSAGE_HERE')))
        ;
    }
}
```

Javascript:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $("#fpassf").click(function(){
            var email = $("#email").val();
            var password = $("#password").val();

        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "<?php echo base_url('Login_cntrl/ajax_login') ?>",
            data: {email:email, password:password},
            success: function(data) {
                data = JSON.parse(data);

                // success in ajax does not mean successfully login, so check again
                if (data.status == 'success') {
                    alert(data.message]); // login success message defined in action
                } else {
                    alert(data.message); // login failed message defined in action
                }
            },
            error: function() {
                    // error in ajax means HTTP error, not login error
                    alert('Request failed!');
                }
            });
        });
    });
</script>
```